# Doubt : Need suggestion to buy laptop in budget for using Ubuntu

Tags: laptop

I'm from France and I'm searching for a laptop to run Ubuntu on it and to start (/continue) to learn programming. I've got a budget of ~300€ (Let's say $400 but they usually do $1=1€ .. I often found laptop twice expensive in euros than in dollars)

I watched for Chromebooks but their low SSD capacity doesn't please me :/

And I'm even more restricted because a lot of laptops are sold in U.S but not in France :(

Thank you for your help !

(Excuse me for my English xD)

Comment: Are laptops not available in a (nearby) major electronics store?

Comment: I don't really know any good Ubuntu friendly French laptops, sry. But an advice is that you buy a used one, then you can get it cheap but still rather fair quality.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started is to go to a used computer store and purchase an older laptop--you don't need much to run Ubuntu. Then have the store help you with installing Lubuntu (a lightweight Ubuntu variant for laptops).

If you really wanted to go bare bones cheep just to learn to program, as an alternative to the laptop, why not go with a Raspberry Pi?

http://www.adafruit.com/raspberrypi

Just add a cheap monitor and keyboard and you're good to go.

You can use Linux--but, probably not Ubuntu.

P. Todd

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I already made my choice on a refurbished ThinkPad T410 2537 but thank you :)